# WPF ListBox data validation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have a ListBox of string items where I want to validate the strings every time a string is added or removed.

Below is the code I've cobbled together, but the problem is that ValidateAddresses is never called when the ObservableCollection Addresses changes.

Intended behavior is that when an invalid string is found, a red border should be shown around the ListBox with a tooltip that displays the error message.

This INotifyDataErrorInfo setup works fine for TextBoxes, so I dunno what I am doing wrong here.

ViewModel

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(ItemViewModel), "ValidateAddresses")]
public ObservableCollection<string> Addresses
{
    get
    {
        return item.Addresses;
    }

    set
    {
        item.Addresses = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Addresses));
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>

            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Name="TextErrorTemplate">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"/>
                            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Red"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Item.Addresses, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedAddress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Validation method (never called)

```
public static ValidationResult ValidateAddresses(object obj, ValidationContext context)
{
    ItemViewModel item = (ItemViewModel)context.ObjectInstance;

    if (item.Addresses.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string address in item.Addresses)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(address, @"[^\w]"))
                return new ValidationResult($"{address} is not a valid address.", new List<string> { "Addresses" });
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: Why `Addresses`'s getter and setter reference `item` ?

Comment: `item` is a class that inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataErrorInfo and where the ObservableCollection Addresses is. XAML and ValidateAddresses references `item` as well.

Comment: That's probably the point, you have to bind to `Adresses` and not to `Item.Adresses`.

Comment: Actually no, `item` and `Item` in the above code examples are correct. It's just that `Item` references to ViewModel while `item` references to Model. In hindsight, should've perhaps used names to differentiate them better. My earlier comment was a bit off in this regard. Apart from the validation, the ListBox works correctly and as intended.

Comment: Upon further research I noticed that the validation works fine when the entire collection changes, but it still won't fire when adding or removing items. I suspect this has something to do with PropertyChanged vs CollectionChanged events. NotifyPropertyChanged apparently does nothing in an ObservableCollection set accessor and this is why the validation never fires upon adding or removing items. I have no idea what I should do to work around this.

Comment: For further clarification. ObservableCollection Addresses is an instance within ItemViewModel. This application manages multiple instances of ItemViewModel and when ItemViewModel object changes, validation of Addresses is triggered. It is also triggered under few other conditions, all seemingly related to PropertyChanged event of ItemViewModel. This confirms the validation method itself works, but is not triggered when adding or removing items from Addresses,

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding following in class constructor for each ObservableCollection I had.

```
Addresses.CollectionChanged += (sender, eventArgs) => { NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Addresses)); };
```

I tried to look into circumstances upon which unsubscribing from events is required to prevent memory leaks, but it does not seem like this is one of these cases so cleanup shouldn't be required.

Null check is not required because ObservableCollections are all initialized in Model class constructor.

Thank you for your replies.

And this is the code for NotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```